# Node throws unsupported engine error during build, but actual node version is greated than required

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'm encountering an unsupported node version in my CI, which runs from a Docker image

```sh
Triggering build execution...
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=16.13.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"7.18.1","node":"v16.4.2"}
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-26T20_58_56_716Z-debug.log
Error occured during the build.
```

Note that the actual version `16.4.2` > `16.13.0`, so this error should not be occurring?

I do have this exiting out with a stderr because strict mode is on `engine-strict=true`, but either way the error occurs.

(No issues locally, where I am also running Node 16)

Comment: No, 16.4.2 < 16.13.0

Comment: Don't know how I overlooked that. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it @HansKilian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you misread the version numbers. 13 > 4.

From https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/:

```
Node.js 16.4.2      2021-07-05
Node.js 16.13.0     2021-10-26
```